# Passing Variable to setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am new to react. In my program, the user is asked to click on a button, and according to that button, the state is changed.

This is the rendered section:

```
<button onClick={this.togglePage(2)}>Click Here</button>
```

This is the part before:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.togglePage = this.togglePage.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      currentpage: 1,
    };
  }
  togglePage(page) {
    this.setState({
      currentpage: page,
    });
  }
```

Is the way I am passing  a value here correct? I am getting an error saying "Maximum Update Depth Exceeded"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a function, not to call it immediatelly

```
 <button onClick={() => this.togglePage(2)}>Click Here</button>
```

As currently written you call `togglePage` in render which causes state update and rerender blowing the call stack.

Comment: Oh I see. this goes too even if I am not passing a value? something like a just toggle (true/false) function ?

Comment: @DarkProfessor If you call the function instead of passing it as a callback - then  yes. `onClick={fn}` - ok `onClick={fn()}` - not ok unless `fn` returns a new function :)

Comment: I see what you mean. How about the `this.togglePage = this.togglePage.bind(this);` ? I don't need to change `this.togglePage` ?

Comment: This becomes redundant if you are using arrow functions in `render`. If you need to create multiple `togglePage` callbacks with different values you could rewrite your code by creating `makePageToggler(currentpage){ return () => this.setState({ currentpage })}` and the call it `onClick={this.makePageToggler(2)}`

Comment: You don't. That statement, as the function name `bind()` suggests, is used to bind the name `togglePage` of the context `this` to the function `togglePage` you implemented. 
Though, you can write that function in this way: `togglePage = (page) => { ... }`, and you will not need nay binding

Comment: Notice in case of `makePageToggler` it is ok to make a call because it returns a new function.

Answer (score 0):

one more approach would be to not bind it in constructor,instead bind it in the button tag as shown below,

```
<button onClick={this.togglePage.bind(this,2)}>Click Here</button>
```